# What does EXPECT_HRESULT_SUCCEEDED means in googletest?

Tags: c++, googletest

I have found 4 `googletest` which are

```
ASSERT_HRESULT_SUCCEEDED(expression);
EXPECT_HRESULT_SUCCEEDED(expression);
ASSERT_HRESULT_FAILED(expression);
EXPECT_HRESULT_FAILED(expression);
```

my question is, what does this tests do according to proper `expression`. What will be the response in which kind of `expression`? Can you explain with example??

Comment: asserts [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687197(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: what is `expression`?? Can you please provide an example??

Comment: @jbsu32 `expression` is any statement that yields a `HRESULT` (e.g. Windows API function calls).

Comment: What do you not understand about [the documentation of Windows HRESULT assertions](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#windows-hresult-assertions)?

Comment: @MikeKinghan what actually is the response of the `googletest`s like `EXPECT_HRESULT_SUCCEEDED` ??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I guessed that, but, is it something like `a=10;b=10; if(a==b){}` or anything near to that?? what is the response of that test then??

Answer (score -1):

What I think is when we need to test something in customized form: EXPECT_HRESULT_SUCCEEDED(exp)

Example:
EXPECT_HRESULT_SUCCEEDED((number % 2 == 0) && (number <= 10) && (number >= 0));

unlike others:
EXPECT_EQ(), EXPECT_GT() ... which does only a specific check condition.

Comment: You may want to read a bit about what a HRESULT is before tackling this one.